# What does "Crew: Top of your mind!" mean in commercial aircrafts?

Tags: commercial-aviation, crew

On a flight this year in Europe, the pilot or co-pilot announced midflight "Crew: Top of your mind!" via the loudspeakers. The crew didn't visible react on that and I couldn't notify any change in the flight after that. What does this announcement mean?

The flight was either with Swiss, Air Serbia, SAS or IcelandAir. Unfortunately, I can't remember which one.

Comment: Can you remember which part of the flight this was? And I'm guessing it was in English?

Comment: It was more or less midflight and it was in English

Comment: Just a wild guess, it could have been related to a previous conversation between the captain and the flight crew, intended to remind the flight crew about something.

Comment: Despite being in English, it may come from English-as-a-second-language crew, so they could have meant something completely different (lost in translation). Whatever it was, it is not a standard call-out.

Answer (score 1):

Could it rather be « crew: top of climb » which some airlines use, but 2 things contradict this: a TOC mid flight is unlikely and although used by some airlines it is more the top of descend we indicate to the flight attendants for them to start preparing for landing.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard any variation of "top of descent" other than something very close to "cabin crew, prepare cabin for landing", but it's been a while since I flew commercially.

Comment: ToC for the last step climb?

Comment: Top of climb sounds reasonable. By mid flight I wasn't referring to the middle of the flight, but more to the normal flight instead of the start or the landing. Sorry for the confusion. But why does the pilot announce the end of the climb?

Comment: These is probably internal SOP's(Standard Operating Procedure) i.e implemented by the company itself maybe to signal the cabin crew to start a procedure(serve drink, prepare meals in the galley etc...)